# Microsoft Owin Logging - Web Api 2 - How do I create the logger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am trying to add logging to my app using Web Api 2 and Owin, so I started using Microsoft Owin Logging, which requires an `ILogger` and `ILoggerFactory`, that has been implemented and it works great when I need to log anything inside the STARTUP method or any of the Owin Middleware components.

For example, when I am in the `Startup` method I can create the logger using:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Creates configuration
        var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Configure WebApi Settings
        WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);

        app.SetLoggerFactory(new OwinLog4NetLoggerFactory("Default"));

        var logger = app.CreateLogger<Startup>();
        logger.WriteInformation("test log");

        // Enabled WebApi in OWIN
        app.UseWebApi(configuration);
    }
```

Where "OwinLog4NetLoggerFactory" is my custom ILoggerFactory implementation.

So far, so good... but... How can I create the logger when I am in the actual web api action method?... I tried accessing the `Request.GetOwinEnvironment()` and the logger factory is not in the dictionary.

For example:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public int Get(int id)
    {
        // Create logger here

        return id + 1;
    }
}
```

I know I can create a static class with a reference to the Logger Factory or even Injection to add the logger to the api controller, but that seems too complicated for something that should be already there.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone answer the actual original poster's question? The one answer below is not what he asked.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend writing your middleware so that you can handle the logging outside of the controller:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public LoggingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
            //handle request logging

            await Next.Invoke(context); 

            //handle response logging
    }

}
```

Then in Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        appBuilder.Use<LoggingMiddleware>();
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

The request would then come in, hit the request logging code in the LoggingMiddleware, hit the controller code and then response would be logged on the LoggingMiddleware on the way back.

However, if all you are wanting to do is send an object through from middleware to the controller you can use `context.Set("loggingObject", loggingObject);` in the middleware and then 
`var loggingObject = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<LoggerClass>("loggingObject");` in the controller.

Comment: Thank you Sam, but that only lets me login BEFORE and AFTER the call to the Controller... not INSIDE the controller. I ended up using Log4Net inside each controller/class.... As recommended by Trevor, I could use a logging abstraction, so I do not have to create a direct dependency to Log4Net, but I wanted to use the internal logging abstraction provided by Microsoft Owin Logging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding logging code in every method, I create a MessageLoggingHandler  that can be registered in Global.asax.cs once, and it then logs every Request and Response.

Here is the code that I use, you can modify as per your requirements:

First Create a MessageHandler class that inherits from DelegationHandler:

```
    public abstract class MessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var corrId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var requestMethod = request.Method.Method.ToString();
        var requestUri = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        var ipAddress = request.GetOwinContext().Request.RemoteIpAddress;

        var requestMessage = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        await LogMessageAsync(corrId, requestUri, ipAddress, "Request", requestMethod, request.Headers.ToString(), requestMessage, string.Empty);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        await LogMessageAsync(corrId, requestUri, ipAddress, "Response", requestMethod, response.Headers.ToString(), responseMessage, ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + "-" + response.ReasonPhrase);

        return response;
    }

    protected abstract Task LogMessageAsync(Guid CorrelationId, string APIUrl, string ClientIPAddress, string RequestResponse, string HttpMethod, string HttpHeaders, byte[] HttpMessage, string HttpStatusCode);

}

public class MessageLoggingHandler : MessageHandler
{
    protected override async Task LogMessageAsync(Guid CorrelationId, string APIUrl, string ClientIPAddress, string RequestResponse, string HttpMethod, string HttpHeaders, byte[] HttpMessage, string HttpStatusCode)
    {
        // Create logger here

        //Do your logging here
    }
}
```

Then in your Global.asax.cs, you need to register the above created MessageLoggingHandler:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageLoggingHandler());
```

Just be aware, this will log every request and response, will full message body. This can take a lot of space very quickly (depending on your API's usage). So you may need to tweak this (for example - keep records for a month or so, or ignore 200-OK responses etc)

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately I do not need to log each request/response (FYI, in the Owin world, you normally do that thru a Middleware). I need to create the logger because I need to log "some debug or warning messages" in some actions. Thank you again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Common.Logging library in your applications, available on NuGet. Common.Logging gives you a common interface for using your preferred logging solution. It solves a lot of issues like yours. Here is an example using Common.Logging with NLog:

In your controller, you would access it like so:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
  {
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger<MyController>();

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] int id)
    {
      Log.Debug("Called Get with id " + id.ToString());
      return Ok();
    }
  }
```

Pick up the latest Common.Logging.NLog package on NuGet (as of this writing, it should be Common.Logging.NLog41). Then in your web.config, you would configure Common.Logging to use your NLog configuration:

```
<common>
  <logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog41">
      <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
      <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
    </factoryAdapter>
  </logging>
</common>
```

Here are some additional links:

https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging

https://cmatskas.com/an-introduction-to-common-logging-api-2/

Comment: Thank you... I ended up using Log4Net directly in each controller class, but the idea was to use the build-in logging abstraction (not "another" package). Thanks!