# Logging in startup.auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to add logging in startup.auth file in my c#/asp.net web application. I have googled everywhere but couldn't find much information. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the version of ASP.NET that uses `Startup.auth.cs` file? It isn't used in ASP.NET Core, for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429462/microsoft-owin-logging-web-api-2-how-do-i-create-the-logger

Comment: @Dai yes we are using the version of ASP.NET that uses Startup.Auth.cs. It isnt .net core.

Comment: @juanvan, thanks for the link. I was just wondering do I have to write a custom middleware for that. Isnt there any other way to do it!?

Comment: You van use Log4Net or similar i'm sure, you'd just need to write the logger code then to the api.