# Can I get IIS type logs from Microsoft.OWIN.Hosting.WebApp self hosting?

Tags: c#, iis, owin

I have a self hosted application written in C# that I would like to capture IIS type logs.  Is there a way to get this?

Comment: Actually duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429462/microsoft-owin-logging-web-api-2-how-do-i-create-the-logger Create your own logger and then write to your own log files in w3c format.

Comment: You can also refer to this link: [https://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction](https://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction).